# Return records where regexp not matched but does not contain word

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to return MySQL records where they don't end in a specific way but I'm having trouble getting what I want (and describing it to be honest).

The records are URL's of the following format:

```
/artist/all/page666 (Do return)
/artist/foo-fighters/page666 (Don't return)
/albums (Do return)
/albums/page666 (Don't return)
```

So I *do want* records that end in all/page666 but I *don't want* ones that end in any_word_other_than_all/page666.

Using

```
LIKE '%all/page%'
```

would get me half way there but it won't include anything like

```
/albums
/vinyl
```

So if I have a REGEXP that excludes **any_word_other_than_all/page[int]**, I would get everything I want.

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this? (first thing that comes to mind..)

```
SELECT .. WHERE myfield REGEXP '/all/page[0-9]+$' OR myfield NOT REGEXP '/page[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: Yup, that seems to be the ticket. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a single regexp expression?